# objective - C: Adding to a Previously saved NSUserDefaults in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

I am making a game in Xcode which in includes a scoring system in each level. Here I have some code that gets an `NSString` (`passedValue1`) by using a delegate.

Heres the code for the delegate:

```
LevelCompleteLevel1
```

**.h**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface LevelCompleteLevel1 : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UILabel *label;

ViewController *secondviewData;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)ViewController*secondviewData;
```

**.m**

```
ViewController *second = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.secondviewData = second;
secondviewData.passedValue1 = label.text;
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
```

In the `.m` I send the a value from a label in the current `viewcontroller` to another `view controller` the value I send is called `passedValue1`

Once I have sent the value I need to display and save in my `ViewController`

```
ViewController
```

**.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UILabel *label;
NSString *passedValue1;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *passedValue1;

@end
```

**.m**

Firstly I ... `@synthesize passedValue1;`

Then i add the code to receive the value in my `viewDidLoad` and display my value in a `UILabel`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    if(passedValue1){
        label.text = passedValue1;

        NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defults setObject:label.text forKey:@"labelkey"];
        [defults synchronize];
    }
    label.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"labelkey"];
}
```

Once I have displayed the value I then save it into a label using a `NSUserDefault`. However, once I have replayed my game and have another score value I would like to add the new `passedValue1` value to the currently saved value...

**For example:**

say I play my level and I get the score value of 10. The value is then saved and I replay my level. I would then like to take the saved value and add it to the value i just scored. So thats say the second value I have scored is 20. I would then like my code to add them together and give me a value of 30.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    if(passedValue1){
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSObject * object = [prefs objectForKey:@"lablekey"];
        if(object != nil){
            NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defults setObject:passedValue1 forKey:@"lablekey"];
            [defults synchronize];
        }
        else{
        NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSInteger readScore=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"labelkey"] integerValue];
        NSInteger newValue=readScore+[passedValue1 integerValue];
        [defults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newValue] forKey:@"labelkey"];
        [defults synchronize];
        }
    }
    label.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"lablekey"];

}
```

Comment: First read your current value from userdefault and save it in another variable then add it with new one and then save latest in userdefault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read from userDefaults, add your current score:

```
//assuming passedValue1 is your new score

NSInteger readScore=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"labelkey"] integerValue];
NSInteger newValue=readScore+[passedValue1 integerValue];
```

Then again save this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newValue] forKey:@"labelkey"];
[defults synchronize];
```

**EDIT:** **You had a typo in labelKey, that is why I stored it in a string and used it, so that even by mistake you may not end up with any typo error.**

Change you method to :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *key=@"labelKey";

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    if(passedValue1){
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSObject * object = [prefs objectForKey:key];
        if(object != nil){
            NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defults setObject:passedValue1 forKey:key];
            [defults synchronize];
        }
        else{
            NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            NSInteger readScore=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key] integerValue];
            NSInteger newValue=readScore+[passedValue1 integerValue];
            [defults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newValue] forKey:key];
            [defults synchronize];
        }
    }
    label.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: +1 darn it... this time you were about 30 seconds faster than me

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: But I took 6 minutes to find the answer :)

Comment: I am getting a error with this code the error I am getting looks like this.                                                                                                                    Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'NSString', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform

Comment: @ThomasStone: Now for your clarity I wrote in multiple lines, check again. and tell which line produces the error. And there was a silly mistake, passvalue1 is string not integer :p

Comment: The problem is with this line here:                           NSInteger newValue=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"labelkey"] intValue]+passedValue1;

Comment: use `NSInteger newValue=readScore+[passedValue1 integerValue];`

Comment: The code solved the error however does not correctly function

Comment: i read and store it in  readScore. your new score is saved in passwedValue1. Then i add and save it in newValue. nslog all three and check which one is not working. I have used your codes only, so please check.

Comment: could you tell me how i can check if there is already a default saved because i think that is the problem. Thanks

Comment: Can you please check out my edit and tell me what I'm doing wrong.Thanks

Comment: sure...gimme some 10 min time

Comment: @ThomasStone: in viewDidLoad method do you see correct label.text value?

Comment: No... Nothing is displayed

Comment: The code you have given now displays the value of the first time i play but does not add up when i play the second time

Comment: because the code is in viewdidload. you need to keep on saving it whenever you scored.

Comment: I can't do that because the score is being transferred through delegate

Comment: you can save from other place too. no need to replace from viewDidLoad.

Comment: Sorry but I do not quite understand

Comment: is there any alert or something that says your game is over?

Comment: Yes I have a separate viewController for that

Comment: there is very small mistake which i cant debug from here

Comment: Okay thanks for all of your help if you find the problem please comment back